# node js reinstallion error at time of version checking

Tags: node.js, reactjs, konvajs-reactjs

```
C:\Users\dilda>node v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dilda\v'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v18.16.0.

Node.js version check issue after uninstallation: Even after completely uninstalling Node.js and reinstalling it, I'm encountering an error when trying to check the version. What could be causing this persistent issue, and how can I fix it?

I'm encountering an error in my React.js project after reinstalling Node.js. I believe the issue might be related to the previous configuration of Node.js. Here's an overview of the situation:

I had Node.js previously installed and configured for my React.js project.
To resolve some issues, I decided to uninstall Node.js completely from my system and then performed a fresh installation of the latest version from the official Node.js website (https://nodejs.org).
However, when I run my React.js project now, I encounter an error